# Regex pattern : Validating a single occurence

Tags: regex

I have implemented the following Regex pattern

```
^[\d,|+\d,]+$
```

It validates the following pattern

> 14,+96,4,++67

I need to invalidate ++67 from my pattern and I need to keep values with only a single leading + sign.
How should I change my Regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\+?\d+(?:,\+?\d+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBJCOG/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - an optional `+` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\+?\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a sequence of patterns:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\+?` - an optional plus
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
^(\d,|\+\d,)+$
```

Square brackets use every character or character class within, which does not appear to be what you really want. For disjunction you need round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
^(\d+\,?|\+\d+,?)+$
```